# Problem that figures were not drawn in expected cell location on grid layout using canvas

Tags: python, kivy

In the following code, there are problems (1) and (2) according to the title.

If kvLang is used as described in this code, the figure (blue ellipse) will be drawn to the expected Cell position (@(1, 1) = upper left).
(However, the character string specified by text: is not displayed at this time. Please tell me how to display text characters .... Problem (1))

I have intended to have coded a Python script to draw with .add_widget method followed to the kvLang.

In this script, the yellow ellipse appears in the lower right instead of the expected Cell position ((2, 2) => lower left) ... problem (2)

For the purpose, it is necessary to add a widget to Grid Laytout using the .add_widget method so that the shape drawn in canvas can be displayed in the cell.

Please tell us how to solve it.

```
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Ellipse
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

Builder.load_string('''
<MyGridLayout@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    Label:
        text:"From Kv_1" #(1)Not show. What's problem?
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb:0,0,1
            Ellipse:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
''')


class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Button(text="From_Py_1"))
        self.add_widget(Button(text="From_Py_2"))
        labl = Button(text="From_Py_canvas_1")
        self.add_widget(labl)
        with labl.canvas:
            # (2) Expected to draw at cell(2,2) which is same locaton as the lable of "From_Py_canvas_1" but not.
            Color(rgb=(1, 1, 0))
            Ellipse(pos=labl.pos, size_hint=labl.size_hint)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: You just need to use `canvas.before:` instead of `canvas:` in your `kv`. This draws the ellipse before the text, instead of after (obscuring the text).

Problem 2: Your `Ellipse` is the using the current properties of the `labl`, which are default values until the app is displayed. To fix that, create the `Ellipse` after by using `Clock.schedule_once()`. In the modified code below, I saved a reference to `labl` in order to access it in the `draw_yellow_ellipse()` method:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Ellipse
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App

Builder.load_string('''
<MyGridLayout@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    Label:
        text:"From Kv_1" #(1)Not show. What's problem?
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb:0,0,1
            Ellipse:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
''')


class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Button(text="From_Py_1"))
        self.add_widget(Button(text="From_Py_2"))
        self.labl = Button(text="From_Py_canvas_1")
        self.add_widget(self.labl)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.draw_yellow_ellipse)

    def draw_yellow_ellipse(self, dt):
        with self.labl.canvas:
            # (2) Expected to draw at cell(2,2) which is same locaton as the lable of "From_Py_canvas_1" but not.
            Color(rgb=(1, 1, 0))
            Ellipse(pos=self.labl.pos, size_hint=self.labl.size_hint)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Also, I don't think the `Ellipse` honors `size_hint`. Perhaps you meant to use `size=self.labl.size`. And if you do that, you will again have an `Ellipse` obscuring, in this case, your `Button`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much, Mr. John Anderson.